# adding together 2 queries in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

still pretty newish to sqlalchemy/sql as a whole, and im trying to solve a certain issue. i have 2 queries, one returning a list of messages sent by the current user, and another returning a list of messages received from another user:

```
messages_from = u.messages_received.filter_by(author_id=user_id).all()
messages_to = u.messages_sent.filter_by(recipient_id=user_id).all()
```

my goal is to add together these 2 queries so that they return something like this:

```
user1 | this is the message content | <timestamp>
user2 | this is another message     | <timestamp>
user1 | this yet another messsage   | <timestamp>
```

im not sure what to use to achieve this. would i use a join? or something else? any help would be really appreciated! <3

Comment: In SQL to combine 2 sets you use a UNION.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you !! that worked! <3

Comment: You can use UNION here. LIke query = query1.union(query2)